# Can you make extend public functions into private, or somehow hide them from external use?

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a few levels of extending classes and functions but at the third layer I want to hide said functions.

I am still using all classes and their public variation of those methods but at the last level, I don't want to expose them.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very good in classes and maybe someone else provide a better one.

I think you can't hide it but you can override it:

```
public override function foo(){
    throw new Error("You can't access this method !");
}
```

Now user can see it from code hint and access it but can't use it.
when user tries to access it, he/she/it will see the error.

H☺pe this helps.

Comment: Hmm, this should break some of the other code of the class, if the function in question is called internally. If it's not, say it's an interface, it might not break anything, but it still has a potential to break working code. Although the question itself contains such ideas, it's better not to encourage them.

Comment: Yes you are right.it may break something.but when he wants to remove this function,so this isn't anything serious!

Comment: No, he said he's not to *remove* but *hide*, that is, if the call is external, the code should return an error or whatever, but if it's from within a class, the code should do something properly. Say if you write `class A { public function foo(){bar(1);} public function bar(i:int){...} }` and `class B extends A {...}` in which you want to hide that `bar` from outside, calling `foo` against an object of type B will also result in an error.

Comment: Check my second answer.

Answer (score 0):

Another way without destroying the function:

in this smart way,we need another function that calls the hidden function:

```
package{
  class A{
    protected function hidden(i:uint){
    ...


    }

    public function hiddenCaller(n:uint){
    hidden(n);

    }

  }
}
```

Now in the extended class:

```
package{
  class B extends A{


    public override function hiddenCaller(n:uint){
    //hidden(n);
    throw new Error("You can't access this method !");
    }

  }
}
```

now in the extended classes,for calling "hidden function" you should call `hidden()` and from external,`hiddenCaller()`.

and because in class b, the `hiddencaller` won't call `hidden`,the `hidden` can't be called externally!

h☺pes this one helps !

Comment: See, the core point still remains with the other answer - redesign interface of a superclass, if you want to do tricks. Now you have a protected function in here - a redesign.

Comment: now where is the problem?? function is accessible from subclasses and inaccessible from externals?

Comment: No problem as is, but a workaround by redesigning. The initial state of OP's question is that `hidden` is public.